# Getting the following build error under iOS

Tags: nativescript

I'm using latest NS, TNS and tns-ios and getting the following error

`node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/styling/gradient.d.ts(7,25): error TS6143: Module '../../css/parser' was resolved to '/Users/asrock/Documents/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/css/parser.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.`

I cleaned my project - and now the typescript compiler fails and exit.

Using TS 2.4.2.

NS 4.1, TNS-CORE 4.1 and TNS-IOS 4.1

This is the `tns build iOS` output

`
Support for Node.js ^6.0.0 is deprecated and will be removed in one of the next releases of NativeScript. Please, upgrade to the latest Node.js LTS version.

Support for macOS 10.12 is deprecated and will be removed in one of the next releases of NativeScript. Please, upgrade to the latest macOS version.

Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/asrock/Documents/test/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-sass.js
Found peer node-sass

Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/asrock/Documents/test/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js

Found peer TypeScript 2.4.2

node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/styling/gradient.d.ts(7,25): error TS6143: Module '../../css/parser' was resolved to '/Users/asrock/Documents/test/node_modules/tns-core-modules/css/parser.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.

TypeScript compiler failed with exit code 1`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that error and I managed to fixed it. If you're using `nativescript-angular` you need to upgrade your angular version to 6 and it's dependencies.

You can follow this link https://www.nativescript.org/blog/upgrading-to-nativescript-webpack-0.12.0. `Nativescript-core` or `nativescript-angular`.

Hope this helps! Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the response - but I'm not webpacking. It's a core JS project. I think I started getting this after upgrade to 4.1.

Comment: I did a full re-install and still getting the error. Using ns, tns-core, iOS 4.1 and typescript 2.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Needed typescript@2.7.2.

Nice if NS printed a message somewhere.